# How to say "see everything there is to see" in casual French?

Tags: expressions

> {I said}: Je serai de retour quand j’aurai ***regardé tout ce qu'il faut regarder*** dans cette ville !

I wonder if this is the French equivalent of the following English construction.

> I'll be back once I ***see everything there is to see*** in this city!

There is a nearly identical expression in German, with the „zu“ having the same function as the "to".

> Du siehst mich wieder, wenn ich in dieser Stadt ***alles gesehen habe, was es zu sehen gibt***!

But I don't suppose it sounds idiomatic to do the same with French and apply « à », as in « il est **à** noter que ... », to this particular sentence, does it?

> Je serai de retour quand j’aurai ***regardé tout ce qui est à  regarder*** dans cette ville !

Comment: Tu peux aussi dire "quand j'aurais écumé cette ville"

Comment: Note that « regarder » means “to look at”. The closest equivalent of “to see” is « voir ».

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The most natural way of saying it would be:

> ... quand j'aurai vu tout ce qu'il y a à voir...

With:

- *voir* over *regarder*
- *tout ce qu'il y a à* + verb

Comment: Ja, it does flow well! ;) But how about when a phrasal verb is several words long:  « ... quand j’aurai **mis la main sur** tout ce qu'il y a à **mettre la main** ...  »?

Comment: vielleich Tout ce qu'il y a sur quoi mettre la main ?

Comment: @Alone-zee "... quand j'aurai mis la main sur tout ce sur quoi mettre la main ...". I think **"il y a"** is not the best phrasing to use in this context.

Comment: I'd go with _quand j'aurai mis la main sur tout ce sur quoi il y a à mettre la main_.

Comment: @Alone-zee I'd probably say *“...quand j'aurai **mis la main** sur tout ce qu'il y a à **ramasser**...”*, simpler than mentioning the whole phrase again, and just as efficient in transmitting the information.

Answer (score 9):

This is another very natural way to say that, despite it being more informal :

> Je serai de retour quand **j’en aurai fait le tour**

Answer (score 0):

I guess a more idiomatic way to say it would be :

```
... quand j'aurai tout vu de cette ville.
```

Without the repetition, you imply that you mean "everything possible" within this context (i.e. everything you would be able to see).

I join @AlexisLeGal on his answer. The expression "faire le tour de" is often used in various context and means that you have (or need to) covert the subject.

```
Il est nécessaire de faire le tour de la question.
```

Could be translated by

```
It is necessary to deal with every possibility.
```

But it's a very "context-wise" expression.